# Meteor get autovalue _id inside collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, collections, meteor

I have this field which is working as I want

```
tagSlug: {
    type: String,
    label: "slug",
    optional:true,
    autoValue: function() {
      if (this.siblingField('tag').isSet) {
        return URLify2(this.siblingField('tag').value);
      }
    }
  }
```

But I also want to make another field named `nameSlug` which needs two fields to be slugged, `_id` and `title` if I use `this.siblingField('title').value` I get title value but nothing hapens if I use `this.siblingField('_id').value` this may be because `_id` is not a field inside the form... The final output I want is something like this `this-is-awesome-title-xDux1if` the last param is `_id` cutted to 6 or 7 characters I don't know what I will do yet in order to not create large slug strings, but you get the idea.

So basically what I want is to access `_id` field from inside collection for `autoValue` another field.

I'm using `meteor-autoform` so I didn't create any `Whatever.insert` method because they're created automaticaly.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to store it, you can use [virtualfields](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) or [collection-helpers](https://github.com/dburles/meteor-collection-helpers)

Comment: Actually I need to store it, that's why I use autoValue inside my collection

Comment: In that case you need to define the _id yourself. You add _id in your schema and generate one with  `Meteor.Collection.ObjectID` if you want a mongoDB generated index.